# How to call a Multipurpose Bar?

Tags: terminology

First of all, i'm not 100% sure i'm in the right place to ask this, but my question is strongly related with User Experience but is an actually naming issue, i'm so stucked on the definition of this.

Long story short i'm building a component that looks like a progress bar but actually can be multifunctional. For instance can describe both the risk of reach the 100% of something (CPU usage for instance) or the estimated progress of reaching the 100% of some task ( i.e: Installation progress ).

How would you call this? Do you see any other relevant use case in which this can be used?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by naming it? Who will be seeing the name and what do you need to convey to them by the name? Is there a reason they wouldn't understand than a "progress bar" couldn't indicate progress toward a number of different goals?

Comment: How about "meter"?

Comment: HTML has [the `meter` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meter) for the first scenario and [the `progress` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) for the second...I think "meter" would be suitable for either one, if you have to use the same name for both. (Like @MattSmith said above.)

Comment: Maybe "indicator".

Answer (score 2):

You can use the term **Gauge**

Definition:

> An instrument that measures and gives a visual display of the amount, level, or contents of something.